# Enable an enterprise deployed extension from the chrome store without prompting the user

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to install a Chrome extension from the Chrome store to the managed workstations on my network in such a way that users (or at least users with administrator privileges) can temporarily reinstall it if necessary to troubleshoot issues.

I have tried the Force-installed extensions setting in Group Policy, but this prevents disabling or removing the deployed extensions. Instead, I tried Chrome Extension policies (https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532015), but with this method the extension is disabled by default due to Chrome security policies, requiring the user to manually approve it.

I realize that this is expected behavior to prevent application developers from auto-enabling a malicious or unwanted extension without the user's knowledge, but I am an enterprise admin trying to deploy a sanctioned extension to my managed machines.

How can I deploy and automatically enable an enterprise-installed extension without user interaction on my managed workstations, but allow that extension to be temporarily uninstalled?

Comment: Maybe it's not possible so here's a workaround: write a simple utility that sends a message to your server where another utility listens to it and toggles the force-install policy for the client machine that sent the message.

Comment: Hm, that's actually not a bad idea, though it would be much simpler to run a script on the local workstation to delete the registry entry that enforces the extension. It should be enough to remove it temporarily until it gets reapplied by group policy.